# Pandas dataframe indexing: Use of '.values' for different index occurrence frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Imagine a dataframe like that:

```
     A    B
ID
1    4    5
2    6    7
2    6    8
```

If I want to access the values for ID=1 in column A, I can do the following:

```
df.ix[1, 'A']
```

For ID=2 in column A, this works:

```
df.ix[2, 'A'].values
```

Is there a way to combine both statements without e.g. using a try/except statement? I couldn't find a nice way for doing this....

Comment: When you do like that, not just this, the next of the code would also need to be handling two cases (first case where it returns scalar value) , the second case where it returns array.

Comment: Right, except for converting the scalar to an array afterwards, too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use lists (or tuples, slices, etc) as indexes. Example -

```
In [63]: df
Out[63]:
    A  B
ID
1   4  5
2   6  7
2   8  9

In [64]: df.loc[[1],'A'].values #Works for `.ix` as well.
Out[64]: array([4], dtype=int64)

In [65]: df.loc[[2],'A'].values #Works for `.ix` as well.
Out[65]: array([6, 8], dtype=int64)
```